# How can I configure shortcut keys in all modes of vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to configure a shortcut key that can be used in both edit mode and normal mode, usually two commands are required:

```
:nnoremap <C-s> :w<cr>
:inoremap <C-s> <esc>:w<cr>a
```

Is there any way to combine them into one instruction that can act on multiple modes at the same time?

Comment: "Compile mode"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help map-table`:

```
         Mode  | Norm | Ins | Cmd | Vis | Sel | Opr | Term | Lang |
Command        +------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
[nore]map      | yes  |  -  |  -  | yes | yes | yes |  -   |  -   |
n[nore]map     | yes  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -   |  -   |
[nore]map!     |  -   | yes | yes |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -   |  -   |
i[nore]map     |  -   | yes |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -   |  -   |
c[nore]map     |  -   |  -  | yes |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -   |  -   |
v[nore]map     |  -   |  -  |  -  | yes | yes |  -  |  -   |  -   |
x[nore]map     |  -   |  -  |  -  | yes |  -  |  -  |  -   |  -   |
s[nore]map     |  -   |  -  |  -  |  -  | yes |  -  |  -   |  -   |
o[nore]map     |  -   |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  | yes |  -   |  -   |
t[nore]map     |  -   |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  | yes  |  -   |
l[nore]map     |  -   | yes | yes |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -   | yes  |
```

shows that Vim has `*map` commands that cover more than one mode but it doesn't a have one that covers all modes. You can thus cover all modes with:

- `:map`,
- `:map!`,
- `:tmap`,
- `:lmap`,

and you must use two `:*map` commands for normal mode and insert mode.

But the RHS of your two mappings are not identical so, even if such a `:*map` command existed, you couldn't use it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to add a shortcut to apply changes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, I leave my config in case it helps

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please avoid posting pictures of text, as others would need to type it off instead of copy and paste

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and paste the text of your config rather than a screen shot.